# Change Security Role to Business Unit from only blank and Organisation CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013, security-roles

In CRM 2013 I would like Business Units to have distinct Products that aren't shared amongst them.

However you can only set Products Security Role as "Organisation" or "None Selected"

How would I be able to specify Business Unit Security settings?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Entities, can be owned by Organization, User or a Team. Product Entity is owned by Organization so it can be viewed by whole organization. Organization-owned entities typically contain data involving something that belongs to or that can be viewed by the whole organization. Organization-owned entities cannot be assigned or shared.

Have a look at [Entity Ownership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955302.aspx) and please check this [blog](http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/entity-ownership-in-crm-2011/) for more.